# Telerik MVC basic example of Button click event and Pass model from View to Controller

Tags: model-view-controller, telerik-mvc

I am new to MVC Telerik controls. I am trying to click on button and pass the model from view to controller that is happened in simple MVC. But in telerik how it will happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
    .Name("textButton")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "btn-primary" })
    .Content("Add BusinessUnit")
  )
```

And in javascript

```
  $('#textButton').on('click', function ()
  {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("add business unit error rendering page");
        }
         });
  });
```

Between Telerik button and html button the only difference is styling. You can use normal html button and button click events as it is working now and just add css class to the button. k-button and k-primary are kendo styling classes

```
   <input type="submit" value="Create" name="Command" class="k-button k-primary" />
```